# Jackson parse JSON into Java Map

Tags: jackson

I have such JSON:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "product": {
        "id": 1123456,
        "context": {
          
        }
      },
      "items": [
        
      ]
    },
```

and a code that reads it:

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef 
          = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/mocks/Docs.json");
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeRef);
```

But I don't want the simple `Map<String, Object>`, I want to map into a map that looks like `Map<String, MyRepresentation> map`:

Is there a direct way to do it, or I need first to read it into Map<String, Object> and then manipulate it manually and fill the MyRepresentation object?

Comment: Have you tried to specify your class in the TyepReference?`TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, AccountManagerStatistics>>() {};`

Comment: If your json represents a `Map<String, AccountManagerStatistics>` why don't you just specify that in the type reference?

Comment: @Andrey, ofcourse I did, and I got such an error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com....datastruct.AccountManagerStatistics` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 2, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["docList"])

Comment: try mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeRef.getClass());

Comment: @Ayush; it won't work: Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends TypeReference to Map<String,AccountManagerStatistics>

Comment: I do not see the purpose of using map here, JSON is very simple for list purpose where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @silentsudo; I have to use map, this is the requirement... and this was my concern actually, if to read it maybe as a list (or map of Object) and then manipulate it to fit the required map structure!

Comment: Please try to read it into POJO class then, as per the requirement manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

the JSON file structure doesn't correspond to the classes at all.
`ConditionSummary` looks like a type of `contextData` element accessible as `docList[i].product.contextData` if it had `id`, which is defined in the `product` element.
also, `AccountManagerStatistics#map` is not public and doesn't have `@JsonProperty` annotation, so it is out of json for now.
try creating the sample file first if you sure the classes represent the truth:

```
Map<String, AccountManagerStatistics> map = createStubData();
new ObjectMapper().writerFor(new TypeReference<Map<String, AccountManagerStatistics>>() {}).writeValueAsString(map)
```

or try to modify your classes to match the data,
which is probably what should be done here.
then you could start from the top and introduce a proper class instead of using `Map<String, X>`,
BTW no need for `HashMap` in `TypeReference`:

```
//@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
  @JsonProperty("docList") //or @XmlElement("docList")
  public final List<Doc> docs;
  ...
  @ConstructorProperties({ "docs", ... })
  public Root(List<Doc> docs, ...) {
    this.docs = List.copyOf(docs);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did something similar by creating Pojo for Doc which includes another Pojos to fit the json structure, and then I did the manipulation by looping over docs and populating my map accordingly.